# Java Generics Covariance vs Contravariance

Tags: java, generics

Questions asked inline within codes.

```
class A1{}
class B1 extends A1{}
class C1 {}

public class X {

    public void meth(List<? super B1> l){
        l.add(new A1());//why this is not a valid syntax,why we can only add new B1() ?
    }

    public void meth2(List<? extends A1> l){
        //and here, why can't we add anything ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of `List<? ... >` is that you *don't know* what type the list is supposed to contain.

You can't add a `B1` to a `List<? super B1>`, because it might actually be a `List<B1>`, which cannot contain an `A1`.

You can't add *anything* (other than `null`) to a `List<? extends A1>` because you don't know anything about what type it's supposed to contain.  It might be a `List<some class that inherits B1>`.